# Placeholders html5 should stay empty

Tags: jquery, html

I have a lost password feature:

1. html form with a JSON call that when submitted and user/email is correct sends an activation code
2. after success, jQuery creates a new form(and removes the old one)

Code:

```
$('form.lost').remove();
$('section#content').html('<form method="get" class="newpass"></form>');
$('form.newpass').append('<h1>New Password</h1>');
Cufon.replace('h1');
$('form.newpass').append('<div class="stage2"><input type="text" name="sCode" placeholder="Code" required="Code is required." id="codex" /></div>');
$('form.newpass').append('<div class="stage2"><input type="password" name="sPassA1" placeholder="New Pass" required="Password is required." id="passwordx" /></div>');
$('form.newpass').append('<div class="stage2"><input type="password" name="sPassA2" placeholder="Confirm" required="Confirmation password is required." id="confirmx" /></div>');
$('form.newpass').append('<div class="submit"><input type="submit" class="hitme" value="Update" /></div>');
```

The weird thing is that the fields are already filled with values that I don't want, even the password field. How do I stop this behavior?

Comment: is it filled with the `placeholder` (e.g. "Code") or is it the browser's autocomplete functionality?

Comment: What do you mean filled with values? What exactly is in there?

Comment: set attribute `autocomplete="off"`  http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/text#Example_A    Following post edit, now i guess you are looking for form reset method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about the browser's password manager. You can instruct most browsers to omit it for current form/control with the `autocomplete` attribute, valid at both [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-autocomplete) and [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-autocomplete).

It's a standard attribute in HTML5 but it used to work in earlier versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just reset the form immediately after

```
$('.newpass')[0].reset();
```

Where .newpass is the class of the new form